# Cannot deselect all tabs in Phonegap's TabBar UI

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I'm using the TabBar plugin with PhoneGap and everything is working successfully. However I wish to deselect all tabs at the end of a function.

On the console log I can see that the functions are all successful until the line `window.uicontrols.selectTabBarItem('');` whereupon the function finishes and - worst of all - the tab is still selected.

I have tried selecting a different tab (in case it was my syntax) but this will not work either: `window.uicontrols.selectTabBarItem("foo");`

How can I make the tabs all deselect - or at least regain *some* control over these tabs? Because it seems as though I have none...